# A setter with no getter

Tags: javascript

```
var NS = ( function ( window, document ) {
    // ... snip
    var g_debug;
    function test( value )
    {
        g_debug = value;
    }
    return {
        test: test
    }
} ( window, document ) );
```

Comment: the function test returns nothing, aka `undefined`, so that's not an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
NS.test
```

does **not** call the function. That's just a **reference** to the function, and the console will print the function source as the value of your console command.

When you write:

```
NS.test(true)
```

in the console, the console prints the return value from the function. Since the function has no `return` statement, it's always `undefined`.

You should probably declare `g_debug` with `var` someplace if you haven't.